# Expected value of successful student which may become a practitioner

Tags: probability

> The disribution of a marks in a specific course is $N(76,8)$.
>
> a. find the probability a student will get mark higher than 90.
>
> b.find the probability that of 100 student who took the course there will be at least 4 who got higher than 90.
>
> c.The lecturer is looking for a great student in order to ask him become a practitioner next year. He asks the student one after another if they got higher than 90. What is the expected value of number of student he need to talk with, until finding somebody appropriating?

a. If I'm not mistaken we are just lookign for $P(X> 90) =1-\frac{\Phi(\frac{90-76}{8})}{8}$ which equals 0.91356.

b. Number of student who get higher then 90 distributed binom (where $n=100,p=0.913$) so again if i'm not mistaken we can take $1- \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^3\binom{100}{i}p^i(1-p)^{100-i}$ which equlas $1-1.6\cdot 10^{-98}\approx1$. How can I get the exact result without computer (my calculator can't calculate these powers).

c.Here I'm stuck. we want to find the expected value of X=number of appropriating students so that's exactly as $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{100}i\cdot P(X=i)$. We can say that $P(X=i)=P(\text{Lecturer asked i-1 failures})\cdot P(\text{one appropriating student})$. The i-1 failures are maybe in probability of $(1-p)^{i-1}$ and the probability of finding successful student is maybe $\frac{1}{\binom{100}{k}p^k}(1-p)^k$ but I can't define myself the connection between i and k or whether I'm in the right way.

Am I right with C? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) The probability that $X\gt 90$ is $1-\Phi\left(\frac{90-76}{8}\right)$. You had an extra $8$, which changes the answer considerably. It is in any case clear that we cannot have that high a proportion over $90$.

(b) Now let $p$ be the probability we got as an answer to the first question. The probability there are at least $4$ over $90$ is $1$ minus the probability there are $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$.

The probability there are exactly $k$ over $90$ is $\dbinom{100}{k}p^k(1-p)^{100-k}$.

Putting the pieces together should not be difficult. It will not strain the capacities of the calculator.

(c) The number of "trials" until the first success has **geometric** distribution, with probability of success $p$.

It is a standard fact about this kind of geometrically distributed random variable that the mean number of trials until the first success is $\dfrac{1}{p}$.

**Remark:** It seems likely that for this numerical problem you are not expected to *derive* the formula for the mean of the geometric.  I would guess you are just expected to quote and use.  The derivation is not particularly difficult, but the approach you started on is not the simplest.